# Dynamic fill in gridlayout

Tags: java, android

I tried to design a menu in my application dynamically using `gridLayout`. The design that I made can fill the layout that was removed with the next layout.

Previously I used `gridView` to overcome this problem, but the process will be slow if it is processed by a device with low memory. Thus causing blanks when entering the main menu.

When I create it with a `gridLayout`, I try to hide one item in the same line. I expect the output is white blank can be filled with the next layout but what happens is the blank white appears if the layout is hidden is the layout in the same line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.handoko.gridlayoutexample.MainActivity">

  <GridLayout
      android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
      android:columnCount="2"
      android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
      android:padding="14dp">

    <!-- Row 1 -->

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Me"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Family"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lovely"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Team"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calendars"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

  </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you set visibility `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`?

Comment: there is no difference even though I set INVISIBLE or GONE

Comment: `INVISIBLE`  means that view remains with its space and `GONE` means that view will completely hide without any space of it.

Comment: I know, and I already set GONE, but it's still like that